# How to read 二、三日

Tags: kanji, readings

If you have the two separate words, it's 二日{ふつか} and 三日{みっか}. But how are they read together? ふた、みっか, に、さんにち, some combination thereof or something else entirely?

Source sentence for the curious:

> アキちゃんは広いお屋敷で二、三日ゆったり過ごしてくればいいのよ。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is read 「にさんにち」.

Colloquially, people say 「にさんち」 as well.

Comment: I doubt 「にさんち」 is a standard Japanese.

Answer (score 14):

It reads に、さんにち (the comma is purely orthographic, you may or may not write it out).

Similarly, we say...

> 一、二日　いち、ににち
>   三、四日　さん、**よっか** ← *irregular!*
>   四、五日　し、ごにち
>   五、六日　ご、ろくにち

Longer span equivalents are hardly heard, perhaps because we come to use "a week" (一週間) or other higher units then, I suppose.

ふた、みっか *might* actually sound surprisingly comprehensible to native speakers, but it never exists.

Comment: For 1~2, it is also common to say "一日、二日" (colloq. "いちんちふつか") (Perhaps dialectal, I'm not sure.)

Comment: あー、何かいろいろあるっぽいですね http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/7434195.html 個人的には上に挙げたのしか使いませんが、「１、２日」と書いて「いちにちふつか」と読む（読ませる？）パターンもあったりと、なかなか深いです。

Comment: おお，色々あるっぽい．ともかく5,6日まで挙げておられるのに +1 です．